# How can I insert multiple rows into a Many-to-Many table based off several columns in a different table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm performing a data migration to a new database with a very different structure. Using SQL Server & T-SQL.

Here is a SQLFiddle example of my tables and where I have gotten so far:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d179b/1

I have four tables:

**CallNotes**:

```
    Id, uniqueidentifier
    OldCallRecordId, int -- Used for migrating only, not in final
    Content, nvarchar(100)
```

**CallTopics**:

```
    Id, uniqueidentifier
    Name, nvarchar(50)
```

**CallNoteCallTopics**:

```
    CallNoteId, uniqueidentifier
    CallTopicId, uniqueidentifier
```

**OldCallRecords**:

```
    Id, int
    CallTopicOne, bit
    CallTopicTwo, bit
    CallTopicThree, bit
    CallTopicFour, bit
```

I am trying to get all the `true` `CallTopic*` values from `OldCallRecords` into `CallNoteCallTopics.CallTopicId` during an `INSERT` statement

All the other tables already have data in them.

I'm currently trying with a `CASE` statement, but that's only getting me the first true value, which isn't what I want:

```
INSERT INTO CallNoteCallTopics
    SELECT
        CallNotes.Id,
        CASE
           WHEN OldCallRecords.CallTopicOne = 1 
              THEN (SELECT CallTopics.Id 
                    FROM CallTopics 
                    WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic One')
          WHEN OldCallRecords.CallTopicTwo = 1 
             THEN (SELECT CallTopics.Id 
                   FROM CallTopics 
                   WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Two')
          WHEN OldCallRecords.CallTopicThree = 1 
             THEN (SELECT CallTopics.Id 
                   FROM CallTopics 
                   WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Three')
          WHEN OldCallRecords.CallTopicFour = 1 
             THEN (SELECT CallTopics.Id 
                   FROM CallTopics 
                   WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Four')
        END
    FROM 
        OldCallRecords
    LEFT JOIN 
        CallNotes ON CallNotes.OldCallRecordId = OldCallRecords.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because when one of the candidate column hits corresponding `CASE WHEN` then it will be output, the same row will not be checked again.

You can try use `UNION`

```
INSERT INTO CallNoteCallTopics
 SELECT
   CallNotes.Id
   ,(SELECT CallTopics.Id FROM CallTopics WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic One') as CallTopicId
 FROM OldCallRecords
 LEFT JOIN CallNotes
 ON CallNotes.OldCallRecordId = OldCallRecords.Id
 WHERE OldCallRecords.CallTopicOne = 1

UNION 

 SELECT
   CallNotes.Id
   ,(SELECT CallTopics.Id FROM CallTopics WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Two') as CallTopicId
 FROM OldCallRecords
 LEFT JOIN CallNotes
 ON CallNotes.OldCallRecordId = OldCallRecords.Id
 WHERE OldCallRecords.CallTopicTwo = 1

UNION 

 SELECT
   CallNotes.Id
   ,(SELECT CallTopics.Id FROM CallTopics WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Three') as CallTopicId
 FROM OldCallRecords
 LEFT JOIN CallNotes
 ON CallNotes.OldCallRecordId = OldCallRecords.Id
 WHERE OldCallRecords.CallTopicThree = 1

UNION 

 SELECT
   CallNotes.Id
   ,(SELECT CallTopics.Id FROM CallTopics WHERE CallTopics.Name = 'Call Topic Four') as CallTopicId
 FROM OldCallRecords
 LEFT JOIN CallNotes
 ON CallNotes.OldCallRecordId = OldCallRecords.Id
 WHERE OldCallRecords.CallTopicFour = 1
```

Comment: This did it for me! Thank you! I made some small edits to it: you compared against `OldCallRecords.CallTopicTwo` twice, and they check to see if they are equal to `1` only, since it's a bit value. But you can see the results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fdbc3/3  Thank you!